# Should I delete a used pointer which i created in a function?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Yo,I was messing around with singly Linked LIsts in C++ and I came across this confusion.I created a pointer in an `insert` function and I wasn't sure if it was going to be deleted afterall.

I thought i could delete it if I just pushed it a few blocks like so: `temp = temp->next->next` But it looks silly.

```
void List::insert(int data){
    Node* newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        head = newNode;
        std::cout << "empty";
    }else{
        Node* temp = head;
        while(temp->next!=nullptr){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
        delete temp; //If i remove this the program works ok and it is reasonable,since i delete the ref
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure I should delete the node,but I am not 100% sure i have to.Any clues?

Comment: Don't use raw pointers and `new` / `delete` at all, you [ain't gonna need it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: And don't implement linked lists! Why oh why do people do this? The most useless data structure ever.

Comment: No, it doesn't do what you expect. You remove the object just before `newNode`, so you both remove object in `insert` function and yo lose forever the newl creaded node.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Because teachers ask them to do so. It's pretty much the simplest data structure, right after vector. And honestly, if you don't implement your own silly linked list, how will you know how does it work and how costful it is to use?

Comment: In a second look,I dont even have to delete `temp` since I didnt allocate any head memory with it.I just pointed it to head.Am i wrong?

Comment: Yeah pretty much @Yksisarvinen .I guess my man Neil just went straight from `if` and loops to programming AIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clue: Consider `List::size()`. How many nodes are there before the insert, how many after the insert? `new Node` creates a node, and `delete temp` deletes a node.

Now if you get these things right, you might still have bugs where you delete the wrong node, but at least `insert` will be right.